# Issues with printing and removing filament residue

Tags: creality-ender-3

When I print at the end when it is done the prints are lighter than they should, and they are thin enough that I can scrape the bottom away.

My second problem is that my filament gets stuck on the support rods and stops the filament from coming through the extruder.

And the final problem I have is when the bottom of my prints get stuck and won't come off and I need to learn how to clean it.

(The bed can come off and my printer is an Ender 3 Pro)

Comment: Welcome 3D Printing SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [Tour](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3D printing.SE! SE websites are driven by questions and answers, your question contains multiple questions which makes it more difficult to answer as there are multiple answers. Please read the [help] section, accessible through the button with the question mark at the top right menu and read [ask]. Please split up your question by adding the other questions in a separate question!

Comment: Frist thought is a non-properly leveled bed (too close). Light models and thin layers may suggest issues with movement or slicing parameters. I don't understand what is "support rods" that stop filament, but anyway it seems very strange... @castleprints did you went through good printer building and calibration tutorial? - I mean something like [Creality Ender 3 assembly and pro build tips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=me8Qrwh907Q) + [Ender 3 V2 Easy Bed Leveling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JSa_r8xgX8).

Comment: 1. Sounds like nozzle is too close to your bed. 2. Please clarify 3. Never done that, but I saw people laying the bed with printed parts into cold/ice water. That may help removing the prints.

Comment: @jp_ thanks for your contribution and the edit, but please try to maintain capitalisation (see my further [edit](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/posts/15830/revisions)). You may also find this post to be useful, [Useful things to check for when cleaning up posts](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/500/4762)

Answer (score 1):

I think I know the answer to your first problem.
Check your flow rates and wall thicknesses in the slicer settings. And if messing with some of those settings doesn't fix the problem, it might have to do with your steps per mm which I posted an answer [here](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/16303/ender-5-with-8-bit-creality-1-1-4-board-issue-with-speed-of-extruder-motor-spin/16334#16334).

The other two problems I'm not really sure about.
Just wanted to at least get one question cleared.